# WebStorm package icon meaning for Dart

Tags: dart, webstorm

When I upgrade Dart, the packages are upgraded as expected. However, in any packages directory, I see the same icon for all the packages. The interesting thing is that some icons have a + and can be clicked to display sub folders - most of the packages do not allow this.

Although the packages are upgraded when I attempt to use them the import does not work - the error is the packages class of a particular package cannot be found.

Please see the attached graphic.

[image]

Is this the expected behaviour? I would expect each package should allow me to see its read-only contents.

### EDIT 1

In the windows explorer, the tree displays as shown below

[image]

Comment: How does it look like if you open zhe directory in Windows explorer. I'd suggest `pub cache repair`

Comment: Please see EDIT 1 the question. I will try pub cache repair although I thought I had done that already.

Comment: The screenshot is not helping. It doesn't show whether the `browser` (or any of the other directories) contains anything.

Comment: All the directories contain the relevant subfolders in explorer

Comment: Everything is finally working now Gunter - all the packages are seen and I can run Dart in WebStorm - thanks a million. Thanks.

Comment: Any idea what fixed it?

Comment: Two possibilities (1) clearing the cache and (2) I found a difference between using a dart project as a dependency in Eclipse vs WebStorm environment. While in eclipse I simply use the name of the project in the .yaml file and refer to it with is absolute path, in WebStorm once I make the one project as a dependency of another, a similar reference described above for eclipse creates a duplicate and has to be removed totally from the .yaml file for the application to run.